# webSphere Liberty: How to generate an output file from an server.xml with only includes

Tags: websphere, generate, server.xml

i have a server.xml with only includes. 
But i want to see the merged one that is used in runtime.

Is there a tool or script that generates a output file from a server.xml with only includes (thats also used in the runtime of liberty ?)

This would make the life of gathering files much easier...

Thanks in advance for any answer!

```
<!-- server.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="${servername} ${type} ${cluster} ${hostname}">
 <include location="${bla}/${bla2}/inc.${bla3}.certs-racf.xml"
  optional="true" onConflict="replace" />
 <include location="${bla6}/${bla2}/inc.${bla3}.certs-racf.xml"
  optional="false" onConflict="replace" />
 <include location="${bla7}/${bla8}/inc.${bla8}.certs-root.xml"
  optional="false" onConflict="replace" />
<!-- server.xml -->
```

what would be the runtime server.xml ?

Comment: Are you thinking more in terms of manually looking over the merge,in a debugging-type of use case?   Or are you more interested in accessing the merge programmatically (writing a tool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSphere Developer Tools do provide this functionality:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/t_merged_configuration_viewer.html

However, the runtime itself does not currently provide such functionality, but there is an RFE opened for it that you can upvote here to show your interest: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=103121

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `config` endpoint enabled via the `restConnector-2.0` feature.  I posted a Q&A touching on the same core question but elaborating some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466475/how-do-i-view-the-merged-liberty-server-configuration-after-includes-and-configd/76466476#76466476).