# How do I view the merged Liberty server configuration after includes and configDropins are combined with the original server.xml?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

## QUESTION

How can I see the "merged" server.xml that the runtime sees after all relevant config is combined according to Liberty precedence rules?

### Background

My project's server.xml has a number of [includes](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/server-configuration-overview.html#include-processing) and potentially some [configDropins](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/server-configuration-overview.html#server-xml) files adding to the original server.xml, with build logic copying different sources into place.

#### server.xml with includes

```xml
<server>
    <include location="dev.xml" optional="true"/>
    <include location="common.xml" />
    <!-- ... -->
</server>
```

#### configDropins

```
/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/quick-start-security.xml
/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/overrides/liberty-plugin-variable-config.xml
```

### Example

E.g. take a config element like **applicationMonitor**.

`<applicationMonitor dropinsEnabled="false" updateTrigger="mbean"/>`

If this element appears more than once across the various config files with different attribute values in each, how can I see the final "merged" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Use the `config` REST endpoint provided by the Liberty `restConnector-2.0` feature.

### STEPS

1. Configure the `restConnector-2.0` feature.

```xml
<server description="my server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
</server>
```

2. Configure administrator access

```xml
<server description="my server"> 
  <quickStartSecurity userName="bob" userPassword="bobpassword" />
  <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="keystorePassword"/>
</server>
```

3. Start the server and access the `https://<host>:<port>/ibm/api/config` endpoint, e.g.: https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/config and login with the configured user:password = `bob:bobpassword`.
4. Look at the JSON response, e.g. for `applicationMonitor` something like:

```json
   {
      "configElementName": "applicationMonitor",
      "dropins": "dropins",
      "dropinsEnabled": false,
      "pollingRate": 500,
      "updateTrigger": "mbean"
   },
```

#### More Options

See the restConnector-2.0 feature [documentation](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/restConnector-2.0.html) for additional options.

#### Note

Not only will you see config elements explicitly configured in server.xml and the includes and configDropins, but you might also see additional elements like `<batchPersistence>` not explicitly configured anywhere.  These might come from the runtime Config Admin service, which can provides defaults at an "inner" layer, relevant to the overall configuration story.

### Further reading

For more information, see the article:
https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/validating-server-connections.html

This article also describes how to use the `config` API to view the values of individual config elements, and also how to do "validation" of certain elements, e.g. a "test connection" of a JDBC `dataSource`.